# Not able to delete file from server with permissions of 644 via PHP script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, permissions

I am trying to delete JPEG files that were uploaded to the server via FTP. The files are uploaded and written with permissions of `644`. The owner and group of the upload directory are `mike` and `mike`.

I have tried changing the owner and group to `www-data`, but that does not seem to work.

I am trying to delete the files with a PHP script using `unlink()`. This works on the production server (which is a hosting service), but not my development server, which is a LAMP setup. This leads me to believe it has something to do with permissions on my development server.

Do you think this has something to do with PHP or Apache configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a file on Unix-like systems, you need write permission on the directory containing it, not the file itself. This is because the underlying operation is actually modifying the directory by removing (unlinking) an entry from it.

In order to do what you want to do, the directory containing the file you want to delete must be writable by `www-data`.

Comment: The only exception to this explanation is that the file has the sticky bit on.

Comment: True. The sticky bit (`+t`) will prevent deletion unless you also own the file.

Comment: @James For the directory to be writable by `www-data`, should I use `chown www-data /var/www/test/images`?

Comment: @James Well, I was able to make it work by changing the `User` and `Group` within `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to `User www-data` and `Group www-data`, and then using `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/test/images` to the upload folder. BUT, the owner of `/var/www/test/images` had previously been set to `mike`. So, changing it to `www-data` now prevents me from uploading to that folder via FTP. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the approach I take for things like this. First, `chown` it back to `mike`. Next, create a new group (e.g. `groupadd uploads`). Then, change the directory's group to the new group with `chgrp uploads _dir_` and give the group write access with `chmod g+w _dir_`. Finally, add `www-data` to the group with `gpasswd -a www-data uploads`. This may require a restart of Apache. This way, `mike` retains access since he owns it, and members of the `www-data` group can also write to it. Use `chmod +t _dir_` to prevent `www-data` from deleting `mike`'s files.

Comment: Sorry, I need to correct myself. After doing the above, members of the `uploads` group, not the `www-data` group, will be able to write to the directory. I confused the `www-data` user and `www-data` group.